# Pervasive v11: Remove optional paramter in where clause

Tags: pervasive, actian

I am using Pervasive V11. In the following query i have an optional parameter called ModelYear. I would like to exclude it from running in the WHERE clause when it is passed as NULL.

```
SELECT  Year,Make,Style,Model,Color1,VIN
                       FROM
                       Vehicles
                      WHERE

                         (VIN ='{VIN}') AND (xyz = '{xyz}') AND 
                       (COALESCE(NULLIF('{ModelYear}', ''), Year))
```

Comment: And what have you tried?  What behavior are you seeing?  Are you getting an error?  I haven't been able to get COALESCE to work in a WHERE clause on V11.

Comment: more like a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT  
   Year,Make,Style,Model,Color1,VIN
FROM
   Vehicles
WHERE
   (VIN ='{VIN}') AND 
   (xyz = '{xyz}') AND 
   (ISNULL('{ModelYear}','') = Year END)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/scalarfunc.05.6.html):

> **ISNULL (exp, value)**:  Replaces NULL with the value specified for value. Exp is the expression to check for NULL. Value is the value
> returned if exp is NULL. Exp is returned if it is not NULL. The data
> type of value must be compatible with the data type of exp.
>
> **NULLIF (exp1, exp2)**:   NULLIF returns exp1 if the two expressions are not equivalent. If the expressions are equivalent, NULLIF returns
> a NULL value.